# Need help solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help solving the following differential equation:

$$(1-a)xy'+(a-a^2-b^2)x-ay-yy'=0,$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants. I know that there are two solutions of the form

$$y=c\cdot x,$$

where

$$c_1=\frac{1}{2}-a+\frac{\sqrt{1-4b^2}}{2},$$

and

$$c_2=\frac{1}{2}-a-\frac{\sqrt{1-4b^2}}{2}.$$

But I would like to know if there are other solutions, and if so, it would be great to be able to find them. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is a homogeneous differential equation of class A: it can be written as
$$ y' = f(y/x)$$
where
$$ f(u) = \frac{au + a^2 + b^2 - a}{u + a - 1} $$
Changing variables to $u = y/x$, we get the separable equation
$$u' = \frac{y'}{x} - \frac{y}{x^2} = \frac{f(u) - u}{x} $$
and thus the implicit general solution
$$ \int \frac{du}{f(u) - u} = \log(x) + C$$
In your case the integration can be done in closed form, but it's a bit messy:

$$ \int \frac{(u + a - 1) \; du}{a^2 + b^2 - a + u - u^2} = -\frac{\ln \! \left(-a^{2}-b^{2}+u^{2}+a -u \right)}{2}+\frac{\left(2 a -1\right) \mathrm{arctanh}\! \left(\frac{2 u -1}{\sqrt{4 a^{2}+4 b^{2}-4 a +1}}\right)}{\sqrt{4 a^{2}+4 b^{2}-4 a +1}}$$

and there's not much hope of getting explicit closed-form solutions with $u$ (and thus $y$) as a function of $x$.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like my problem it pretty hopeless. I appreciate the clarification!!!